# Why this function error: Incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'int' from 'void *'?

Tags: c

Please have a look at the code, clang is giving me the error "Incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to 'int' from 'void *' ", why is it happening?

```
{
#include <stdio.h>  //use printf
#include <stdlib.h> //use random
#include <time.h>   //use time
#define MaxData 100 // Define Max Data
#define MaxRow 10   // 0..9 in Decimal base
#define MaxCol 20   // 0..19

int Data[MaxData];
int Radix[MaxRow][MaxCol]; // Radix is temporary tank. The size is[ 0..MaxRow, 0..MaxCol ]
int N, N1;

void ClearStackPT() // Clear every block=0 and use Radix[0] for SP
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i <= MaxRow; i++)
        Radix[i][0] = NULL; // This position keep the SP
}
}
```

this is my gcc version
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BTW6.png)

Please help me fix this, I really don't know  what happen

Comment: `Radix` is a 2D array of `int`, and `NULL` is not an `int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[dbush](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77165631/why-this-function-error-incompatible-pointer-to-integer-conversion-assigning-to/77165668#comment136035402_77165631) already mentions that `NULL` is not an int. The value of `NULL` is defined as `((void *)0)` in C. So, use an integer zero here.

You have an undefined behavior due to accessing an array out of bounds in the loop condition:

```
i = 0; i <= MaxRow; i++
         ^^^
```

It should be `<` instead.

Comment: @Rohan Bari: excellent reply to the OP's question ("Why is the compiler saying 'incompatible pointer to integer conversion'?").  +1 for pointing out the loop error.

Comment: @ikegami: Other options that conform to the C standard are `0ull` and `(3/5)`. (Technically, the parentheses are not required, but that is an oversight in the standard.)

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: The use of italics when introducing a term in this way indicates it is being defined; “x is a *y*” means “y” is defined to be x, more than the ordinary English sentence “An x is a y.”

Comment: @ikegami @Eric Postpischil, My error is that although `(void *) non_zero` is a possible _null pointer_ (C99 §6.3.2.3 5), _null pointers_ of that form are not valid as a _null pointer constant_.  I was reading into 6.3.2.3 3 something that allowed any _null pointer_ to be a _null pointer constant_ that is not there.  So `((void*)0)`, `((void*)0u)`, `((void*)0L)` (as are `0`, `0u`, `0L`) are valid _null pointer constants_, but not `((void*) non_zero)`, even if `((void*) non_zero)` is a _null pointer_.   Beep beep - comment cleaner coming through on my earlier comments - beep beep.

Comment: @ikegami  Ok, fine, it should compare equal to `((void *) 0`, but it need not have a pointer type depending on the context.  It's hard to imagine why a constant integer expression with value zero would be used in place of an explicit pointer constant, but I suppose there are legacy implementation that do.

Comment: Anyway, the point chux was making was correct, that "The value of `NULL` is defined as `((void *)0)` in C" is incorrect.

Comment: (And since the spec allows it to be an "integer constant *expression*", I was incorrect about it being only `0` and `((void*)0)`. `0u` and `(3/5)` and infinitely many other definitions are also allowed. It can't be `-1` or `((void*)-1)`, though, even if the bit pattern of `NULL` is `FF..FF`.)